# why is FindViewById not coming out? it turns red as a mistake if I write it myself

Tags: android, findviewbyid

Why does FindViewById not work? If I type findView ..., findViewById does not appear, and if I type it myself, it writes error. my code (fragment):

```
public class BiografiyaFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    public BiografiyaFragment() {
    }

    public static BiografiyaFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        BiografiyaFragment fragment = new BiografiyaFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_biografiya, container, false);
}
}
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dCkt.png)

Answer (score 1):

It's a fragment. Therefore, you have to create a object of `View` class in `onCreateView` method. So, the code in `onCreateView` will be,

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_biografiya, container, false);
        // I am assuming a textview here....
        TextView textView=view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the modern way, the best solution is to use ViewBinding.

Usage steps

**build.gradle**

```
   android {
        ...
        buildFeatures {
            viewBinding true
        } 
}
```

**your code**

```
public class BiografiyaFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;
    private BiografiyaBinding binding; // new added.


    public BiografiyaFragment() {
    }

    public static BiografiyaFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        BiografiyaFragment fragment = new BiografiyaFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binding = BiografiyaBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false); // Added
        return binding.getRoot();
}

@Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       // Sample 
       //binding.sampleViewIdName...
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

in the fragment, you have to call this function by associating with view
like

```
view.findViewById()
```

and here in you case, view is

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_biografiya, container, false);
```